# Unable to auto mount usb and "mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist error"

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

Unable to automount USB.

I am trying to enable auto mount usb in Unity. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices) post.

Mean while I faced the error:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usbstick
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist error
```

Before and after connecting USB.

```
ravan@ravan:~$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda5
sda6
sda7
sda8
ravan@ravan:~$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda5
sda6
sda7
sda8
sdb
```

---

```
ravan@ravan:~$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

11        0    1048575 sr0
8        0  976762584 sda
8        1  125952000 sda1
8        2          1 sda2
8        3  267795456 sda3
8        5   17071289 sda5
8        6   41507812 sda6
8        7  104268800 sda7
8        8  420161536 sda8
8       16    3915776 sdb
```

Part of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1018 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

---

```
ravan@ravan:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 120.1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 255.4G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  16.3G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0  39.6G  0 part /
├─sda7   8:7    0  99.4G  0 part /home
└─sda8   8:8    0 400.7G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I have tried posts linked [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mount%3A+special+device+%2Fdev%2Fsdb1+does+not+exist)

**EDIT 1**:

I solved the error by creating partition using `gparted`. Still auto mount problem exists.

```
ravan@ravan:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 120.1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 255.4G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  16.3G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0  39.6G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0  99.4G  0 part 
└─sda8   8:8    0 400.7G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: What dose `dmesg` show ?

Answer (score 1):

your `USB` have only raw disk space. there is no partition. 
see your output `TYPE` of `sdb`:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 120.1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 255.4G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  16.3G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0  39.6G  0 part /
├─sda7   8:7    0  99.4G  0 part /home
└─sda8   8:8    0 400.7G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

First you have to create partition and assign complete space to that partition. then you will be able to do that.

For that you have to go:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

press `n` to create partition and follow other option and assign complete space to this single partition.you can take help from  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384062/how-do-i-create-and-tune-an-ext4-partition-from-the-command-line) to create partition.

**NOTE:** disk never mount

Comment: thanks =), sorry, I have  to edit question, I created partition using gparted. The problem still exists is `automount`.