# Attaching disk to AWS VM causes host to boot into emergency mode

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualization, aws

I have now had this experience in Azure Cloud & Amazon AWS my current issue is on a host running Ubuntu 15.10 but I had similar experiences on CentOS 7.1 and I'm wondering if I'm somehow doing something wrong that is causing the issue.

I add a disk via the aws console and attach it to my host.
The disk shows up as xdvf
I fdisk xdvf and create new partition primary defaults on every option following this guide:
[How do I create and tune an ext4 partition from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384062/how-do-i-create-and-tune-an-ext4-partition-from-the-command-line)

mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xdvf1
mkdir /data
mount /dev/xdvf1 /data

Then I proceed to use the /data mount to install apps download stuff ect.
I then resized the vm to save money(t2.medium to t2.small)

Now I get: 
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.