# How do I clone a failing hard drive to a new hard drive using ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 1TB FAILING hard drive, a brand new 1 TB hard drive, a bootable ubuntu usb, and a working computer.

All I need is a step by step process of how to safely clone as much data as possible from one to the other. NOTE: THE DRIVE IS FAILING.

I know I need to enable multiverse and then install and use `ddrescue` to complete the task. But everywhere I look online, I can't get a straight path to the task. I know that this can be all done within the terminal and that's what I seek.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

> **Caution:** It is *highly* advised you run `ddrescue` from a live USB or similar, and not on the damaged hard drive. Using the damaged hard drive any more than absolutely necessary may cause more (and worse!) data loss.

First off, you're going to enable the `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 (and later, assumed for this guide), this will automatically update your package repositories as well.

Once you have `universe` enabled, we can go ahead and install `ddrescue`:

```
sudo apt install gddrescue
```

Next, find your partitions/disk data. This is *usually* achievable through the `lsblk` and `blkid` commands. On my (example) system, we will be cloning **`/dev/sda`** to **`/dev/sdb`**. Once we have our names, we can just run ddrescue:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3  /dev/sda /dev/sdb /path/to/rescue.log
```

We're going to use the `-d` option to read the disk directly, and the `-r3` to retry a bad block three times before moving on. `rescue.log` is an (optional) log file used to restart a recovery if it is interrupted. You may store it in-memory, but it is highly recommended to store it to an external (third) USB drive.

Let this run, and hopefully your drive will be restored.

For further options, read the manpage for `ddrescue` after installing it. You can access it with the following command:

```
man ddrescue
```

---

A full disk `ddrescue` is doable, but is somewhat frowned upon due to putting unnecessary stress on the disk. If at all possible, try to only recover the minimum amount of data necessary - a single partition, for example. In order to do this, you'll need to [create a partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384062/how-do-i-create-and-tune-an-ext4-partition-from-the-command-line) on your target drive first.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use **`ddrescue'**,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gddrescue
```

which is a tool, that can clone in two steps,

- a quick step to clone the sectors, that are good (and easy to read)
- a slow step to clone the sectors, that are difficult to read, but may still be readable, if trying slowly and repeatedly.

When `ddrescue`is installed, there is a very good tutuorial at

```
info ddrescue
```

Please read it carefully before starting the work. You can probably work along the instructions of one of the examples.

> Example 1: Fully automatic rescue of a whole disc with two ext2
>   partitions in /dev/sda to /dev/sdb. Note: you don't need to partition
>   /dev/sdb beforehand, but if the partition table on /dev/sda is
>   damaged, you'll need to recreate it somehow on /dev/sdb.
>
> ```
>  ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sda /dev/sdb mapfile
>  fdisk /dev/sdb
>  e2fsck -v -f /dev/sdb1
>  e2fsck -v -f /dev/sdb2
> ```
>
> Example 2: Rescue an ext2 partition in /dev/sda2 to /dev/sdb2. Note:
>   you need to create the sdb2 partition with fdisk first. sdb2 should be
>   of appropriate type and size.
>
> ```
>  ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 mapfile
>  ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 mapfile
>  e2fsck -v -f /dev/sdb2
>  mount -t ext2 -o ro /dev/sdb2 /mnt
>    (read rescued files from /mnt)
> ```
>
> Example 3: While rescuing the whole drive /dev/sda to /dev/sdb,
>   /dev/sda freezes up at position 12345678.
>
> ```
>  ddrescue -f /dev/sda /dev/sdb mapfile       <-- /dev/sda freezes here
>    (restart /dev/sda or reboot computer)
>    (restart copy at a safe distance from the troubled sector)
>  ddrescue -f -i 12350000 /dev/sda /dev/sdb mapfile
>    (then copy backwards down to the troubled sector)
>  ddrescue -f -R /dev/sda /dev/sdb mapfile
> ```
>
> ...

---

1. Do not use the drive (more than what is necessary for the cloning).
2. Boot from another drive, for example an external drive, typically a USB pendrive (a persistent live drive made by mkusb is a good candidate, and many  linux repair tools serve the purpose, actually an Ubuntu live-only drive can do it, but if you install `ddrescue`, it will not survive a reboot).
3. Have a third drive ready as the target drive for the cloning. This drive must be at least as big as the original failing source drive (not one single byte smaller), and should have the same size of physical clusters. Check that with `parted`,

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sdx u b p
   ```

   where `x` is the drive letter, for example `a` and `b`, so in this example

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sda u b p

   sudo parted /dev/sdb u b p
   ```
4. It is important to write the `mapfile` to a persistent location, because you want to reuse it from the first step to the next step.
5. If the target drive with the cloned copy has a different size than the source drive (the failing one), and there is a GUID partition table, GPT, you have to repair the backup partition table with `gdisk` or easier with [gpt-fix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#gpt-fix). This is not necessary if there is an MSDOS partition table.

See also the following link,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) - Scroll down to

**Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files**

> If you still have problems, you can use other methods for repair or
>   recovery of the files, that are more powerful but also more risky. If
>   the data are valuable it is a very good idea to make a cloned copy to
>   a card or pendrive of at least the same size, and try to repair the
>   file system and/or recover files from the cloned copy.
>
> Particularly if you suspect bad sectors (a hardware damage on the
>   drive), it is a good idea to clone with ddrescue.